# Javascript Date using forward-slashes vs hyphens

Tags: javascript, date

When I'm creating a new Date object and pass in a date using hyphens

```
new Date("2015-07-02") // I get Thu Jul 02 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)
```

and when I use forward slashes

```
new Date("2015/07/02") // I get Thu Jul 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)
```

notice the time difference: 01:00:00 for hyphens and 00:00:00 for forward slashes

this breaks my code :(

Why this is happening? 
Any workaround for this? (Should I just set time to 00:00:00 when using hyphens?)

I need to be able to compare dates that have forward-slashes with dates that have hyphens and I'm not sure I might need to compare dates with some other symbols.

Is this happening to hyphens only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If** a recent browser **can** interpret the  date string as `ISO-8601` - it **will** do it.

examples :

```
 YYYY (eg 1997)
 YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
 YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
 YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
 YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
 YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

*With this format, your date/time string is interpreted as **UTC**(!!!).*

You should Stick to `"YYYY-MM-DD"` for your date strings whenever possible

Comment: Having it interpreted as UTC is not a bad thing, is it? UTC should be used as a standard anyway, so you should stick to the ISO standard `YYYY-MM-DD` whenever possible.