# How can change the format of Date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date like `2019-02-01`. how can I change it to `February 2019`?

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const d = new Date("2019/02/01");
const m = d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
console.log(m, d.getFullYear());
```

Comment: `Date.toLocaleString()` will return a month name in the user's language, not necessarily English. If OP needs February, then you need to change `'default'` to `'en-US'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this:

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const d = new Date("2019/02/01");
const dateString = `${monthNames[d.getMonth()]} ${d.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(dateString);
```

This will return the month in English, no matter the system's language.

Note that you should use `new Date("2019/02/01")` (with slashes) to specify a date in your timezone. If you use `new Date("2019-02-01")`, then it will assume UTC time, and weird stuff will happen (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199268/13376511) for more info on this).

Comment: Any source where it says slashes = UTC?

Comment: @vanowm It has to do with whether or not JS uses ISO-8601. Here's a SO answer that sums it up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199268/13376511

Comment: @vanowm Oh sorry, I had a typo in my answer. I've updated it to correct it though.

Comment: MDN only states: Date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, while date-time strings (e.g. "1970-01-01T12:00") are treated as local. It is good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

/* you can use the following code to convert date to the required format. */
var todaysDate = new Date();
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var formatted_date = months[todaysDate.getMonth()] + " " + todaysDate.getDate() + " " + todaysDate.getFullYear();

Comment: You can format the answer in a better way

Comment: It needs to be better formatted